# AttributeError: module 'config' has no attribute 'Config'

Tags: python

Untitled.ipynb and config.py are in same folder.
So, I call config.py in Untitled.ipynb
But, jupyter say 'AttributeError: module 'config' has no attribute 'Config'
Why??!!!
Please help me....:(

**Untitled.ipynb**

```
import config
import numpy as np
print(config)
con = config.Config()
#Input training files from benchmarks/FB15K/ folder.
....
```

**config.py**

```
#coding:utf-8
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.optim as optim
import os
import time
import datetime
import ctypes
import json

class Config(object):
    r"""In this class, we set the configuration parameters, adopt C library for data and memory processing. In the following,
    we train models and test models.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./release/Base.so")
        self.lib.sampling.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_int64, ctypes.c_int64, ctypes.c_int64]
        self.lib.getHeadBatch.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p]
        self.lib.getTailBatch.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p]
        self.lib.testHead.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
        self.lib.testTail.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
        self.test_flag = False
        self.in_path = "./"
        self.out_path = "./"
        self.bern = 0
        self.hidden_size = 100
        ....
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not importing a Python package called `config` rather than your local module? E.g. https://pypi.org/project/config/

Comment: I resove it.
Probelm is strange mark in config.py.
Thank you for your comment!